# How to determininate dll is unicode or ansi code?

Tags: windows, dll, visual-c++

I want to call a DLL.
But, I don't know what's the correct charset of the DLL.

So, I don't know my LoadLibrary should use unicode or ANSI code.  Is there any method to know the dll was build in which mode?

Comment: The flavour of `LoadLibrary()` used only affects the arguments passed to it: `LoadLibraryA("mydll.dll")` or `LoadLibraryW(L"mydll.dll");`.

Comment: Do you mean when programming, we don't required to know whether the dll is built in unicode set or ASCII code set.

Comment: All you need to know is what character type the DLL functions expect, which is part of the function declaration.  What character set(s) the DLL works with internally is irrelevant to the caller.

Comment: I'm missing the dll's source code, and the spec of the dll function is full with bugs.  So, I don't know what's the correct charset.